# Show status bar notification even after application is killed in Android

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, kill

I have to make a different kind of notification in my application. The notifications should be shown even if the application is killed from the task manager. The notifications should be stacked one after the another. The existing notification code which I am using is given below.

This is the class for creating the notification:

```
public class TimeAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

     NotificationManager nm;

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      nm = (NotificationManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      CharSequence from = "Scheduled Training";
      CharSequence message = "Please attend the scheduled training";


      PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
        new Intent(), 0);
      Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        "Scheduled Training", System.currentTimeMillis());
      notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
      nm.notify(1, notif);
     }
    }
```

This is the code I am using in the activity to create the notifications:

```
  @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  duration=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.duration_editText);
        dateAndTimeLabel=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.timeTxt);

        updateLabel();
        updateNotification();
        am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

     // On Click Confirm

            confirm=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.confirm_imageView);
            confirm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    getDateTime();
                     count++;
                   setOneTimeAlarm();
                }
            });

      }


     public void setOneTimeAlarm() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
             calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
             calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);





          Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimeAlarm.class);
          PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            intent,count);
          am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
           calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
         }


    void updateNotification()
          {
              hour= dateAndTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
              minute=dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
          }
```

This is not helping me achieve my goal. What should I do? I want to create kind of notification you can find in Ice Age village game.

Comment: "The notifications should be shown even if the application is killed from the task manager" -- since Android does not have a "task manager", please explain *precisely* what you mean by "killed from the task manager".

Comment: Task manager means active application list

Comment: "Task manager means active application list" -- I am sure that "active application list" means something to you. It means nothing to anyone else on the planet. Hence, nobody else can help you. Please explain ***precisely*** what you mean by "killed from the task manager".

Comment: After exiting from an application, go to Settings --> Applications --> Manage Applications --> Running. If you have an alarm manager notification, then after application quit, you will be able to see the application in the above mentioned list. If the application is killed from this list, then no more notifications are fired from the application. I want that even if the application is killed from this list, the notifications will still be fired. Like I was speaking of the Ice Age village game.

Comment: If the user takes the time to go into Settings and stop your app, I doubt that the user wants your notifications to appear. Moreover, the user has other means of blocking your notifications as of Android 4.1, so there is no guarantee that any user will be seeing your notifications. You should be focused on writing a decent app (one that does not cause users to want to stop it from Settings) and having a UX that does not rely upon the `Notification` being visible (since the user can get rid of those).